# What does 'SCV' mean?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

It's most likely an acronym, but what does it mean exactly? (In German it's WBF, bonus points for that one).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the Starcraft 1 manual (where the unit debuted), emphasis mine:

```
SCV Role: Space Construction Vehicle
 Armament: Fusion Cutters
```

> Initially
>   used during the reconstruction of the
>   Tarsonian Orbital Platforms, **the T-280
>   SCV (Space Construction Vehicle)**
>   became a staple in intra-Colonial
>   construction and engineering due to
>   its ability to perform a multitude of
>   tasks, including the construction of
>   new buildings and the transportation
>   of raw resource materials. It is this
>   versatility, and an unmatched
>   reliability, that make the SCV an
>   invaluable tool in rapidly
>   establishing Marine encampments and
>   strike bases on any terrain.

Edit: I found a picture of a German version of the Terran Tech Tree.

WBF stands for Weltraumbau-Fahrzeug (or Weltraumbaufahrzeug)
[image]

Comment: And the German is simply a literal translation of the English, here.

Comment: @JavadocMD Indeed `Weltraum-bau-fahrzeug` in [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#de|en|Weltraum-bau-fahrzeug) provides that exact translation.

Comment: I love it when you use pictures to prove something.  Makes this feel more like a first party source of information

Comment: My favorite is the German localization of Marine: Space-Marine!

Answer (score 7):

It stands for 'Space Construction Vehicle'.  Heres a [link](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/SCV)

Answer (score -2):

SCV = Space Construction Vehicle
WBF (german) = Weltraum Bau Fahrzeug

so exactly the same akronym in german

Comment: The accepted answer already says all of this.